# Is this sequence $x_{n+1}=1+\frac{a-1}{1+x_n},$ with $a>1, x_1>0$, convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

My question: Assume $$a>1, x_1>0, x_{n+1}=1+\frac{a-1}{1+x_n}.$$ Is this sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ convergent or divergent as $n\to\infty$? If it is convergent, give a proof (in this case, the limit is obviously $\sqrt{a}$ ).

This question comes out of the Exercise 1.13, on Apostol's textbook *Mathematical Analysis*, page 26.  The exercise is:  Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers. Prove that $\sqrt{2}$ always lies between the two fractions $a/b$ and $(a+2b)/(a+b).$ Which fraction is closer to $\sqrt{2}?$

I have finished this exercise, then I want to construct a algorithm, based on this exercise, to estimate the square root of $a.$  I have tried, but was heavily stuck. Obviously, it is not monotonic, although its even subsequence $\{x_{2k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ and odd subsequence $\{x_{2k-1}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ may be monotonic. But I can not prove my guess.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: Nitpick: I believe the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ would have limit $\sqrt{1+a}$ if it converges, not $\sqrt{a}$.

Comment: @Nitpick, you are right, thank you! I have made a mistyping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursion map
$$T:\quad x\mapsto 1+{a-1\over 1+x}={x+a\over x+1}$$
is a Moebius transformation with the two fixed points $\pm\sqrt{a}$. Therefore we introduce a new coordinate function $y$ for which these fixed points are at $0$ and $\infty$. This is accomplished by putting
$$y={x-\sqrt{a}\over x+\sqrt{a}}\ .$$
We then obtain
$$y_{n+1}={x_{n+1}-\sqrt{a}\over x_{n+1}+\sqrt{a}}={{x_n+a\over x_n+1}-\sqrt{a}\over {x_n+a\over x_n+1}+\sqrt{a}}=\ldots=-y_n{\sqrt{a}-1\over\sqrt{a}+1}\ .$$
As $a>1$ it follows that $0<{\sqrt{a}-1\over\sqrt{a}+1}<1$, whence $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n=0\ $ (or $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=\sqrt{a}$) unless the starting point happened to be $y=\infty$, which corresponds to $x=-\sqrt{a}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Big hint of the day**

1. Mathematics is about generalizing ideas, and making connection. You should look at the problem you wish to solve, and the one before it (aka **Exercise 1.13**), do you see any similarity? If you don't, please read forwards, and when you have reached the end, come back to think about it.
2. Notice that in your proof of **Exercise 1.13**, you don't need the fact that $a$, and $b$ are both positive integer, in fact, they only need to be any positive real numbers.
3. Try to generalize the problem, i.e, try to prove that: Given $a, b$ be positive real numbers, and $n$ be any natural number, then $\sqrt{n}$ will always lie between $\dfrac{a}{b}$, and $\dfrac{a + nb}{a+b} = 1 + \dfrac{n-1}{a+b}$, and which is *nearer* to $\sqrt{n}$?
4. Now, prove by induction that, since $x_1 >0$, you will, in fact, have that $x_n > 0,\forall n$
5. Fix any natural number $n$, since $x_n > 0$, we can rewrite it as: $x_n = \dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}$, where $\alpha, \beta > 0$ arcording to the formula: $x_{n+1} = 1+\dfrac{a}{1+x_n}$, can you calculate $x_{n+1}$ in terms of $a, \alpha$, and $\beta$? Using the result in **number 2** (there are 2 conclusions you can draw from number 2, and the latter is pretty important), what can you say about this sequence?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Define the sequence $u_{n+1} = a\frac{u_n+1}{u_n+a}$ with $u_1=0$. Using induction it is easy to show that $u_n$ is an increasing sequence that tends to $\sqrt{a}$ as $n\to\infty$. Again using a simple induction we can show that 
$$\forall n\quad u_n < x_n <\frac{a}{u_n}.$$ 
Therefore,
$$\sqrt{a}=\lim _{n\to\infty}u_n\leq \lim _{n\to\infty}x_n\leq \lim _{n\to\infty}\frac{a}{u_n}=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a}}=\sqrt{a}.$$

Comment: your solution is very helpful.  But my question is why you think of the substitution $u_{n+1}=a\frac{u_n+1}{u_n+a}$. Can you explain how you construct this $\{u_n\}$ from $\{x_n\}$? Thanks!

Comment: For the first few members of the sequence write the upper and lower bounds that you can get starting from $u_1=0<x_1<\infty$. The pattern is that $x_n$ is bounded between a $u_n$ and $a/u_n$. Then derive the relation between $u_n$ and $u_{n+1}$ from the recurrence formula for $x_n$.